# test database for react-native app development

Tags: database, reactjs, react-native, testing

I'm in the early stages of developing an app with react-native, and I need a DB implementation for for testing and development. I thought that the obvious choice would be to use simple JSON files included with the source, but the only way I see to load JSON files requires that you know the file name ahead of time. This means that the following does not work:

```
getTable = (tableName) => require('./table-' + tableName + '.json') // ERROR!
```

I cannot find a simple way to load files at runtime.

What is the proper way to add test data to a react-native app?

Comment: What do you want to do in case the table doesn't exist ? Wouldn't a `try/catch` do the trick ?

Comment: I don't care about that case as it is only for development. The point here is that `require(dynamic string value)` won't even compile because require needs a static value, not a dynamic one like this.

Comment: Weird, I never had any error when doing that using `require`, what is the error thrown ?

Comment: The error is `invalid call`. It doesn't give any more information than that the call to require is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find a simple way to load files at runtime.

In node you can use `import()` though I'm not sure if this is available in react-native. The syntax would be something like:

```
async function getTable(tableName){
  const fileName = `./table-${tableName}.json`
  try {
    const file = await import(fileName)
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err
  }
}
```

though like I said I do not know if this is available in react-natives javascript environment so ymmv

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dynamic import not supported by react-native but there is a way so to do this

```
import tableName1 from './table/tableName1.json'; 
import tableName2 from './table/tableName2.json';
```

then create own object like

```
const tables = {
  tableName1,
  tableName2,
};
```

after that, you can access the table through bracket notation like

```
getTable = (tableName) => tables[tableName];
```